# Outdated AngularJS library found in magento2

Tags: magento2, security-scan-tool

What is solution below Error? Any One Can Help?:
**Status**: `FAIL`
**Group**:  `Vulnerability`
**Scan Name**:  `Magento Js Libraries`
**Scan Details**:
`Outdated JS Libraries - Failed. 
Outdated AngularJS library found, response body contains unexpected 'AngularJS v1.2.17-build.178+sha.2406084'`
**Actions**:
`Apply the Magento 2.2.7/2.1.16 Security Update immediately.
Review your site for signs of compromise. Find more information about Security Best Practices.`
[image]

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score -1):

Open angular.min.js from below both locations

vendor\magento\magento2-base\setup\pub\angular

setup\pub\angular

and remove the code

/* AngularJS vX.X.X (c) 2010-2018 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org License: MIT */

i.e whatever in /* to */

This worked for me and now the site is at low risk.